# Importing and merging .csv files with loop in R

Tags: r, loops, csv

I have 20 files named 1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv etc, which I want to read into R and merge using rbind using a loop.
I've tried the code below but I get an error message saying unexpected "[" in the second line.

```
for (i in 1:22) {
  fish[i]  <- read.csv([i].csv)
  combined <- rbind(fish[i], fish[i+1])
}
```

Comment: try `fish[i] <- read.csv(paste0(i, ".csv"))`

Comment: also if you only have 20 files, your loop should only be `1:20` I think.

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast

Comment: for (i in 1:22) {
 fish[i] <- read.csv(paste0(i, ".csv"))
 combined <- rbind(fish[i], fish[i+1])
}

Comment: I tried this but I got Error: object 'fish' not found

Comment: yes, this is because it is not defined before the loop ans so R does not know its index.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once

Answer (score 0):

To put my comment in a answer:

```
# just for rbindlist, there are also base ways to do this
library(data.table)

fish <- list()
for (i in 1:20) {
  fish[[i]] <- read.csv(paste0(i, ".csv"))
}
combined <- rbindlist(fish)
```

Alternative:
Same as `do.call("rbind", fish)` on data.frames, but much faster.